# Example showing how to override TabExpansion2 in Windows PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell, windows-8, powershell-3.0, tabexpansion

Does anyone have an example showing how to override the TabExpansion2 function in Windows PowerShell 3.0?  I know how to override the old TabExpansion function, but I want to provide a list of items for the intellisense in PowerShell ISE.  I looked at the definition of TabExpansion2 and it wasn't easily understandable how I inject my own code in the the tab expansion process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this example should give you a good starting point: [Windows Powershell Cookbook: Sample implementation of TabExpansion2](https://books.google.com/books?id=78w1953mptUC&lpg=PA56&ots=z0ssmJ1_RJ&dq=powershell%20cookbook%20tabexpansion2&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=powershell%20cookbook%20tabexpansion2&f=false). The example code shows that you can add code both before and after the default calls to `[CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput`.

For instance, you can add an entry to the `$options` hashtable named CustomArgumentCompleters to get custom completion for command arguments. The entry should be a hashtable where the keys are argument names (e.g. "ComputerName" or "Get-ChildItem:Filter") and the values are arrays of values that could be used to complete that parameter. Powertheshell.com also has an article about this: [Dynamic Argument Completion](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629180441/http://www.powertheshell.com/dynamicargumentcompletion/). You can also specify custom completions for native executables, using the NativeArgumentCompleters option (again, keys are command names and values are arrays of possible completions).

Once`CompleteInput` has returned, you can store the result in `$result` for further analysis. The result is an instance of the [`CommandCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandcompletion) class. If the default completion didn't find any matches, you can add your own [`CompletionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.completionresult) entries to the list of matches:

```
$result.CompletionMatches.Add(
   (New-Object Management.Automation.CompletionResult "my completion string") )
```

Don't forget to return `$result` from the function so the completion actually happens.

Finally, a note on troubleshooting: the code that calls `TabCompletion2` seems to squelch all console-based output (not surprisingly), so if you want to write debugging messages for yourself, you might try writing them to a separate text file. For instance, you could change the `End` function in `TabCompletion2` to look like this:

```
$result = [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
    $inputScript, $cursorColumn, $options)
$result | Get-Member | Add-Content "c:\TabCompletionLog.txt"
$result
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere formally? How did this information originally get out?

Comment: Sadly I haven't seen any formal documentation, but I'd love to see it if it exists.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example of overridden `TabExpansion2` -
[TabExpansion2.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/FarNet/wiki/TabExpansion2) (disclaimer: I'm the author)
and several used-in-practice profiles with completers for it:

- [Invoke-Build.ArgumentCompleters.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build/blob/master/Invoke-Build.ArgumentCompleters.ps1)
  Argument completers for [Invoke-Build](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build)
- [Mdbc.ArgumentCompleters.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/blob/master/Scripts/Mdbc.ArgumentCompleters.ps1)
  Argument completers for [Mdbc](https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc)
- [ArgumentCompleters.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/FarNet/blob/master/PowerShellFar/Bench/ArgumentCompleters.ps1)
  Argument, input, and result completers

The points of interest:

- *TabExpansion2.ps1* does minimum work on loading. Potentially expensive
  initialization is performed once when completion really happens.
- Overridden `TabExpansion2` provides extension mechanism via one or more
  profiles `*ArgumentCompleters.ps1` in the path. Profiles are invoked once
  on the first call of `TabExpansion2`. Several profiles may come with
  different independent modules, tools, and etc. and used simultaneously.
- In addition to standard custom argument completers and
  native argument completers this custom  `TabExpansion2` supports
  result processors which tweak the results from the built-in completion
  and input processors which can intercept and replace the built-in completion.
- It works around read only empty built-in results in some cases.
- [ArgumentCompleters.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/FarNet/blob/master/PowerShellFar/Bench/ArgumentCompleters.ps1)
  contains an example of an input processor witch replaces the built-in
  completion of types and namespaces with an alternative, more useful
  sometimes.
- Another completer provides completion in comments: help tags (*.Synopsis*,
  *.Description*, etc.) and completion of commented out code, why not?