# How can I modify PowerShell tab-completion to proritise certain file types over others?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

I have a directory containing a large number of files:

```
a.json
b.dll
c.config
d.exe
...
z.exe
```

When I `cd` into this directory and type `.\` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, PowerShell autocompletes the files in this order:

```
> .\a.json
> .\b.dll
> .\c.config
> .\d.exe
> .\z.exe
```

because by default, the prompt iterates through all files in the directory alphabetically.

I would like it to instead prompt me with executable files before any others, i.e.:

```
> .\d.exe
> .\z.exe
> .\a.json
> .\b.dll
> .\c.config
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the default PowerShell function that's used for tab completion, the [mostly-undocumented `TabExpansion2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12291199/70345), the content of which you can obtain by running `get-content function:global:tabexpansion2`.

Because the content of this function may differ on your system, I'm not going to show it in its entirety, only the pertinent part which is the return of the calculated tab completion possibilities (this is from PowerShell Core 7.3.2 x64 running on Windows 10 21H2 x64):

```
... start of TabCompletion2...

End
{       
    if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptInputSet')
    {
        return [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
            <#inputScript#>  $inputScript,
            <#cursorColumn#> $cursorColumn,
            <#options#>      $options)
    }
    else
    {
        return [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
            <#ast#>              $ast,
            <#tokens#>           $tokens,
            <#positionOfCursor#> $positionOfCursor,
            <#options#>          $options)
    }
}
```

Both code paths are calling the static [`System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion.CompleteInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandcompletion.completeinput) method, using different versions of that method depending on the arguments passed to `TabExpansion2`.

At this point you might think that we need to delve into the innards of these methods and tweak them to taste, but thankfully that's not the case. We don't actually need to change how `CommandCompletion.CompleteInput` works - we just want to change the order of its suggestions. Since it's already done the hard bit, we just need to do the reordering!

Hence, modify `TabCompletion2` to the following:

```
... start of TabCompletion2...

End
{
    if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptInputSet')
    {
        $completion = [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
            <#inputScript#>  $inputScript,
            <#cursorColumn#> $cursorColumn,
            <#options#>      $options)
    }
    else
    {
        $completion = [System.Management.Automation.CommandCompletion]::CompleteInput(
            <#ast#>              $ast,
            <#tokens#>           $tokens,
            <#positionOfCursor#> $positionOfCursor,
            <#options#>          $options)
    }

    $exeMatches, $nonExeMatches = $completion.CompletionMatches
        .Where({$_.CompletionText -Like "*.exe"}, "Split")
    $completion.CompletionMatches = @($exeMatches) + @($nonExeMatches)

    return $completion
}
```

It's actually really simple:

- we use the [magic array `Where` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where) to filter the `CompletionMatches` collection that `CommandCompletion` has helpfully already populated for us, splitting it into one part containing the found executable matches and the other part containing the remaining matches
- overwrite the default completion matches with our sorted matches, placing the EXE matches first so they're presented first, and ensuring we use array constructors to overcome PowerShell's propensity for [causing problems by silently returning a single item instead of an array](https://superuser.com/questions/414650/why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string)
- return the completion

With this updated `TabCompletion2` installed into our [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles#the-profile-files) and after reloading said profile via typing `.$profile` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, typing `.\` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> now yields the desired result:

```
> .\d.exe
> .\z.exe
> .\a.json
> .\b.dll
> .\c.config
```

Comment: Very nice. You can simplify the split-and-join operation at the end with `$completion.CompletionMatches = @($completion.CompletionMatches.Where({$_-like'*.exe'},'Split') |Write-Output)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Amazing - I didn't even know that the magic `Where` method existed until today, and I still can't find any documentation for it on MSDN.

Comment: The `.Where` intrinsic method is documented in the [`about_Arrays` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#where) :)

Comment: Thanks again, found it now, updated answer to reflect MSDN link.